# Why is this function only returning one (1st) value in what should be an array of 5?

Tags: php, mysql

I am running an SQL query when my user logs into my app to retrieve a list of 'communities' they are part of.

I am trying to test what values are being returned by pasting the login link directly into my address bar.

It should return an array of 5 entries, but it is only returning 1.

I have tested the SQL query in phpMyAdmin and it returns the correct result.

What am I doing wrong?

This is from `userLogin.php`

```
$communities = array();
$communities = $dao->getCommunities($email);
echo json_encode($communities);
```

Which runs the following function in `MySQLDao.php`

```
public function getCommunities($email){

    $returnValue = array();
    $sql = "SELECT communities.name \n"
. "FROM users \n"
. "join community_players \n"
. "on community_players.player_id=users.id \n"
. "join communities \n"
. "on communities.id=community_players.community_id \n"
. "WHERE users.user_email = '".$email."'";

$result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
        $row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if(!empty($row)){
            $returnValue = $row;
        }
    }
    return $returnValue;
}
```

This is currently returning `{"name":"EnclliffeT"}` in the browser.
However, there should be another 4 entries.

Comment: Because you are only getting the first row from the result set

Comment: `$row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` needs to be in a while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fetching only the first row. Replace these lines:

```
if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
    $row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if(!empty($row)){
        $returnValue = $row;
    }
}
```

with these:

```
if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
    while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       if(!empty($row)){
          $returnValue[] = $row;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: The echo json_encode($communities) is throwing out an issue in Xcode.  Is that something to do with returning the array?

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

Comment: Did you set the `contentType` header to `application/json`?

Comment: Replace these :                                                                         `$communities = array();`
`$communities = $dao->getCommunities($email);`
`echo json_encode($communities);`                                                                 with these:                                                                                                       `$communities = array();
`$communities = $dao->getCommunities($email);`                                  `header (contentType: "application/json");`                                      
`echo json_encode($communities);`

Answer (score 1):

Your `public function getCommunities($email){` is fetching only the first row, no matter how many are returned by the SQL query.

Try to apply the following change:

```
$results = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    $results[] = $row;
}

return $results;
```

Comment: is this in replace of $row = $result -> fetch....

or do I put it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

A query produces a resultset. That resultset can contain 0 to n rows. Therefore you must unload the resultset row by row in a loop of some sort. A while loop is the best way of doing this.

```
public function getCommunities($email){

    // the query

    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    if ( ! $result ) {
        //report error somehow
        exit;
    }
    $returnValue = array();

    while ( $row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $returnValue[] = $row;
    }
    return $returnValue;
}
```